# Can JMeter script run application

Tags: jmeter, performance, load-testing

I've recorded a web script (script is creating a quote for product) using blazemeter, and downloaded the file. After i ran the script from JMeter, for that i got all results in tree, table, etc..

But client wants to validate the test in such a way that when ever we run the script from jmeter, a quote should be created.

Can the jmeter script  run the application and create quote, is that possible?

Comment: What do you mean by a quote?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the script is correct, i.e. it has [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) in place, all dynamic values are [correlated](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-load-testing-scenarios-jmeter-part-1-correlations), all dependent files are present (i.e. files used in the [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)) the test should be environment-agnostic and you can run it from anywhere.

I would also suggest randomizing your script a little bit just in case the application doesn't allow creating duplicate "quotes" (whatever it is) using i.e. [__time() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) to add current timestamp to the created "quote" or [__RandomString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomString) function so "quote" body would be different for each request, etc.